# Как вывести массив svg картинок в create react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, create-react-app

Проект делается на `create react app`, далее `CRA`

**Проблема**: есть массив с названиями картинок, который нужно перебрать и вставить как svg в разметку чтобы иметь доступ изменить цвет обводку и т.д.

До этого собирался галпом спрайт и картинки вставлялись через css класс.

Пробовал использовать `@loadable + svgr cli` - при сборке `loadable` разбивает все файлы который создал `svgr` на бандлы и их получается огромное количество равное количеству svg картинок думаю это не очень правильно.

Также использовал `react app rewired` и `react-app-rewire-svg-react-loader` - это работает, но `react-app-rewire-svg-react-loader` уже не поддерживается, `react app rewired` не рекомендуют использовать в `CRA`